# Why does it do an index scan when there are indexes on all the relevant columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have an index on `car_id` and an index on `ended_at`.

Is this query taking so long because I am ordering it by `id` and I have separate unique indexes?

Would it be better if I ordered it by `ended_at` and then made an index on both `ended_at` and `car_id`?

```
SELECT  "trip_reports".*
FROM "trip_reports"
WHERE "trip_reports"."car_id" = $1 AND (ended_at < '2020-11-03 17:31:09')
ORDER BY "trip_reports"."id" DESC
LIMIT $2
```

Duration is 6.05 minutes.

The query plan:

```
Limit (cost=0.56..4512.17 rows=1 width=1156)
  -> Index Scan Backward using trip_reports_pkey on trip_reports (cost=0.56..9830786.80 rows=2179 width=1156)
     Filter: ((ended_at < '2020-11-03 20:55:57'::timestamp without time zone) AND (car_id = 103638))
```

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..4512.67 rows=1 width=1156) (actual time=976974.363..976974.363 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2071575 read=3222036
  ->  Index Scan Backward using trip_reports_pkey on trip_reports  (cost=0.56..9831877.02 rows=2179 width=1156) (actual time=976974.361..976974.361 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ((ended_at < '2020-11-03 17:31:09'::timestamp without time zone) AND (car_id = 119780))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 22862225
        Buffers: shared hit=2071575 read=3222036
Planning time: 0.113 ms
Execution time: 976975.711 ms
```

Comment: We'd need the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query to give an answer.

Comment: Try a multi-column index. (Your query will only use one index.)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Posted EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS).

Comment: @jarlh Ok, I will try. Is this because it has an Order By in the query?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion:

1. Try creating an index for the `WHERE` condition:

   ```
   create index trip_reports_carid_endtime on trip_reports (car_id, ended_at);
   ```

   *(column order in index is important)*
2. If you did not do it before:

   ```
   vacuum (analyse) trip_reports;
   ```

Comment: how can I vacuum asynchronously?

Comment: postgres use few "workers" to do vacuum - number of max workers is parameter max_parallel_maintenance_workers